# Some html tags are getting overlapped, am new to web development

Tags: html, css

> I have tried `clear:both`, `box-sizing: border-box` but all are
> same,in normal window there is no problem but after resizing the
> browser window size am gettig this error, the div -> button are
> getting overlapped with
> div -> h1

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>Demo Production</h1>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="btn">Watch Video</a>
  <a href="" class="btn">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Okay I will check it out, but can you point me some error?

Comment: @Ava Expected output is " Below the <h1> there will be two buttons", which are all working fine in full size browser window, but overlapping in a smaller window.

Comment: I'm on mobile and I can confirm that they aren't overlapping. They're breaking into two lines due to small screen. Do you want them in the same line?

Comment: Also, one more thing, why giving `1000px` `margin-top`? Give it in relative unit so that it remains consistent on small screen devices.

Comment: @Ava are the two buttons visible below "Demo Production"?

Comment: margin-top 1000px, I was just experimenting stuff

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/KgexdG0
I just reduced the `margin-top` to `5em` and added a black background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for Flexbox. See [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)